# Query on one field, get list of matches "after" based on ordering on other field

Tags: django

Say I have the following table, used to get a list of delta updates from a client. When ever an article record is created, modified or deleted, a row is added to the table below.

```
id | article_id | uuid
---|------------|-------------------------------------
 1 |         56 | 78b69fa0-480b-11e1-b86c-0800200c9a66
 2 |         23 | 87c4fe60-480b-11e1-b86c-0800200c9a66
 3 |         78 | 903973f0-480b-11e1-b86c-0800200c9a66
 4 |         23 | bb3972d0-480b-11e1-b86c-0800200c9a66
 5 |         28 | f05fdd00-480b-11e1-b86c-0800200c9a66
```

A client remembers the uuid from the last synchronization, and includes this in the next request. Say the client already knows about changes 1 and 2 above; he would then include uuid 87c4fe60-480b-11e1-b86c-0800200c9a66 (id=2) in the request. Now, I need to return rows 3-5. If the uuid from the client is not in the table, and error should be raised.

The simple brute force way to to this is to first search based on uuid and then use the id of the found change record (id=2 in this case) to to a search where id > "found_id" (id > 2 in this case).

Is there a more efficient way to query this, i.e. somehow expressing 'give me all rows after this uuid where rows are sorted by id ascending'?

Comment: What makes you think that this "simple way" is inefficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get Django to do it in a single db hit, although it's still a query+subquery, like this:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(id__gt=MyModel.objects.filter(
     uuid='whatever').values_list('id',))
```

Comment: Thanks, had a feeling that a subquery is necessary. Did not know about values_list, which makes the solution elegant and simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django's extra() method and use raw SQL in *where* clause. This will allow you to select all articles in one query. The drawback is that this is highly database-engine specific. Assuming that your model is named Article:

```
articles = Article.objects.extra(where=["id > (
    SELECT t2.id FROM "+Article._meta.db_table+" t2
    WHERE t2.uuid= '87c4fe60-480b-11e1-b86c-0800200c9a66'
    LIMIT 1)"]
).order_by('id').all())
```